# Bootstrap tabs shown.bs.tab not fired on page load

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have several tabs on page and I'm trying to keep the tab active when page is reloaded. I do this by push hash into url:

```
$('.nav-tabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').click(function () {
    window.history.pushState("", "", $(this).attr('href'));
});
```

with code above, I keep tab active even when user reloads the page.

I'm trying to catch `shown.bs.tab` event, but apparently event is not triggered on page reload, but it works when any other tab is clicked

```
$('.nav-tabs a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function () {
    //do something
});
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

## edit

`active` class is removed both from `li` and `div.tab-pane`

I've even tried to call tab.show event manually but it doesn't help

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if(hash) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').tab('show'); //or trigger('click')
}
```

Comment: What is triggering "click" when the page loads? I think you need to call `.tab('show')` to fire the `shown.bs.tab` event.

Comment: Nope, calling `.tab('show')` or `.trigger('click')` doesn't work either. I've updated my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like `.tab('show');` does not fire event on already shown tabs.

Instead I've replaced it with `.trigger('shown.bs.tab');` and it's working as it should, so my code looks like this now:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
if (hash) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="' + hash + '"]').trigger('show.bs.tab');
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you attach the `shown.bs.tab` handler *before* calling `.tab('show')`:

```
// wire up shown event
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    console.log("tab shown...");
});

// read hash from page load and change tab
var hash = document.location.hash;
var prefix = "tab_";
if (hash) {
    $('.nav-tabs a[href="'+hash.replace(prefix,"")+'"]').tab('show');
}
```

**Bootstrap 4** - Select active tab on reload

Code: http://www.codeply.com/go/Yu8wbjeGMZ
Demo: http://www.codeply.com/render/Yu8wbjeGMZ#tab2

Answer (score 2):

`.tab('show');` does not fire event on already shown tabs OR the tabs having active class. Make sure that the element or the parent of the element on which you are trying to fire the event should not have the active class. So the workaround could be delete the active class before firing the event.

i.e.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass("active");
OR
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').parent('*').removeClass("active");

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').tab("show");
```

Answer (score 0):

Last answer - helps. But need to change .trigger('shown.bs.tab') -- not 'show.bs.tab'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).